# Error: constant expression required Android Studio

Tags: java

So i am trying to code a bottom navigationbar in java in Android Studio and i keep getting the Error: constant expression required. The bold R.id. statements below are what causing the error.
Here is my Code of the MainActivity:

```
package com.rpitest.appmudu;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    FavoritesFragment favoritesFragment = new FavoritesFragment();
    ToolsFragment toolsFragment = new ToolsFragment();
    StatusFragment statusFragment = new StatusFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,homeFragment).commit();

        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case **R.id.home:**
                       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,homeFragment).commit();
                       return true;

                    case **R.id.favorites**:
                       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,favoritesFragment).commit();
                       return true;

                    case **R.id.tools**:
                       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,toolsFragment).commit();
                       return true;

                    case** R.id.status**:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,statusFragment).commit();
                        return true;

                }
               return false;



            }
        });
    }
}
```

and that is my code from the menu directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_home"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/favorites"
        android:title="favorites"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_favorites"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/tools"
        android:title="Tools"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_tools"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/status"
        android:title="Status"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_status"/>
</menu>
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong.

I really have no idea whats wrong with the code.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. The syntax of a switch case requires for your cases to be a constant value. like `case "A"`. Using a non constant expression like a reference to a field or a method call is not valid java (And also makes no sense at all from a logical standpoint)

Comment: @user6073886 And yet, this is in every single Android sample on the Google Developer site.

Answer (score 6):

This error may happen when `R.class` has trouble mapping the IDs. Try adding the following two lines in your `gradle.properties`

```
android.nonTransitiveRClass=false
android.nonFinalResIds=false
```

Comment: This is the best answer, do this and you don't have to change any code.

Answer (score 1):

*if you are using **DrawerLayout** & **NavigationView** and you are facing the **constant expression required** issue then try the below code its worked properly.* Use **If() else-if()** instead of **Switch()** Case.

```
  drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationview);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            int id = menuItem.getItemId();
            if(id == R.id.home_menu){
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return true;
            }
            else if(id == R.id.profile_menu) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return true;

            }  }  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like:

```
Map<Integer, Fragment> fragments = new HashMap<>();
fragments.put(R.id.home, homeFragment);
fragments.put(R.id.favorites, favoritesFragment);
fragments.put(R.id.tools, toolsFragment);
fragments.put(R.id.status, statusFragment);

public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment = fragments.get(item.getItemId());
    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I haven't seen the rest of your code so I'm not sure where the best place to create the map would be, but it just needs to be after the fragment objects.

(In newer versions of Java you could even create the map in a single expression, but I don't know if Android supports that.)